# How do I get my Hangman Java file to read a random word in from a .txt file?

Tags: java, file, if-statement, random

```
char hangman[];
Scanner sc = new Scanner( System.in);
Random r = new Random();
File input = new File("ComputerText.txt").useDelimiter(",");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(input);
String words;
```

I want to read in a set of words from a .txt file and have the program select a random word to use in the hangman game.

The below code is for when we get the .txt file to be read inside the code. 
We want to use three different .txt files with a different category each and have the user pick which category they want their word from.

```
//while(decision==1){word=computerWord;}
if ( decision == 1)
{
word=computerWord;
}
else if ( decision == 2)
{
word = countryWord;
}
else if (decision == 3)
{
word = fruitWord;
}
else
{
System.out.println("error, try again");
}
```

Comment: what doesn't work? Do you run into problems? Perhaps create a readstream to read from the file? BufferedReader should do the trick.

Comment: Sorry Bram, I haven't been using java long and only know the basics. The main program is reading in words when we write them like so:            String[] word = {"program", "computer", "download", "database"};     But i want the program to read in these words from a text file and for the file to use the random class to pick a word

Comment: @sarahjane call sc.next();

Comment: Null Saint, do you mean for user input in the second part of the question? Like sc.next() will allow the user to pick an option from the three?

Comment: @sarahjane you have set the scanner to read from your file variable but in order to read from that file call sc.next()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how a file must be read with the scanner class :-

```
    try 
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        File file = new File("ComputerText.txt");

        input = new Scanner(file);

        String contents;
        while (input.hasNext()) 
        {
            contents = input.next();
        }
        input.close();

    } 
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
    }
```

at this point all the file contents will be in the contetns variable, you can then use the split method to split according to your delimeter

Answer (score 0):

Your approach should be:

With following imports:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
```

Make functions that return your desired word:

```
if ( decision == 1)
{
    word = getComputerWord();
}
else if ( decision == 2)
{
    word = getCountryWord();
}
else if (decision == 3)
{
    word = getFruitWord();
}
else
{
    System.out.println("error, try again");
}
```

Implemented in the following way:

```
public String getComputerWord() {
    return getRandomWordFromFile(computerWordsPath);
}

public String getCountryWord() {
    return getRandomWordFromFile(countryWordsPath);
}

public String getFruitWord() {
    return getRandomWordFromFile(fruitWordsPath);
}

//returns random word from ","-delimited file of words
public String getRandomWordFromFile(String path) {
    String fileContent = readFileToString(path);
    String[] words = fileContent.split(",");
    Random rng = new Random();
    return words[rng.nextInt() % words.length];
}


//build string from file by simply concatenating the lines
public String readFileToString(String path) {
    try { 
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));

        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = br.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                line = br.readLine();
            }
            return sb.toString();
        } finally {
            br.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        //Error handling of malformed path
        System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
    }
}
```